# Nested elements in jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, absolute, jsplumb

I'm trying to put together a chart with nested elements that connect to each others' endpoints. As you can see in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xJEXH/), it's not going very well. The JS is reproduced below in full:

```
jsPlumb.ready(function () {
    jsPlumb.importDefaults({ ConnectionOverlays: [["Arrow", { location: 1 }]] });
    var pinCount = 0;
    var pin = {
        endpoint: "Dot",
        isSource: true,
        isTarget: true,
        maxConnections: -1,

        paintStyle: {
            strokeStyle: "#1e8151",
            fillStyle: "transparent",
            radius: 7,
            lineWidth: 2
        },
        connectorStyle: {
            lineWidth: 3,
            strokeStyle: "#deea18",
            joinstyle: "round",
            outlineColor: "#eaedef",
            outlineWidth: 0,
            overlays: [
                ["Arrow", {
                    location: 1
                }]
            ]
        },
        connectorHoverStyle: {
            lineWidth: 4,
            strokeStyle: "#5C96BC",
            outlineWidth: 2,
            outlineColor: "white"
        },
        connector: ["StateMachine", {
            stub: [5, 5],
            gap: 10,
            cornerRadius: 5,
            alwaysRespectStubs: true
        }]
    }

    jsPlumb.draggable($(".container"));
    jsPlumb.draggable($(".reactor"), { containment: "parent" });

    function rebalance(part, side) {
        var ends = $.grep(jsPlumb.getEndpoints(part), function (elem, i) {
            return elem.anchor.type == side
        });
        var len = ends.length + 1;
        $.each(ends, function (i, elem) {
            elem.anchor.y = (1 / len) * (i + 1);
        });
        jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
    }

    function addPin(part, side) {
        jsPlumb.addEndpoint(part, pin, { anchor: side, uuid: "pin" + pinCount });
        pinCount++;
        rebalance(part, side);
    }

    var $c = $("#container");
    var $r1 = $("#child1"), $r2 = $("#child2");

    addPin($c, "Left");
    addPin($c, "Right");
    addPin($r1, "Left");
    addPin($r1, "Right");
    addPin($r2, "Left");
    addPin($r2, "Right");

    jsPlumb.connect({uuids: ["pin0", "pin2"]});
    jsPlumb.connect({uuids: ["pin3", "pin4"]});
    jsPlumb.connect({uuids: ["pin5", "pin1"]});
});
```

Peer node connections, as in `["pin3", "pin4"]`, look sane until you move any part of the chart. Then they explode. Connections between parent/child endpoints never really do what they're supposed to. Removing `position: absolute;` and `draggable` from all elements involved does something half-way passable, but a) still has some placement issues and b) removing those properties defeats the purpose.

General jsPlumb tips welcome, but specifically: Am I doing something wrong that prevents this from lining up properly? Am I misusing some property of connectors/endpoints? Is there a workaround for the placement issue I'm running into here?

Comment: I've made some minor adjustments to your CSS/positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/xJEXH/1/ which make it a bit better. Do not use margin to position elements. Set parent to relative and use absolute positioning on child elements. this works great with draggable.I'm not sure what you try to achive with and what the function rebalance should do. So the Endpoints are still weird. Please explain

Comment: @Jeroen - As I said, I'm trying to put together nested charts. As in, a chart whose nodes can potentially be further multi-element charts recursively. I'll eventually want multiple endpoints on either side of a particular element, and `rebalance` makes sure they don't overlap perfectly. Your edits do improve the situation, but they don't quite do everything I want. In particular, try removing the absolute positioning, dragging one of the child divs, then dragging the parent. What you'll see is the relevant connectors snap to the original position of the child, rather than the new one.

Comment: Ah I think that is because your rebalance function is moving and sorting the anchors. You should place the objects and maybe scale the container based on it's content. Let jsPlumb do the thinking when it comes to anchors. Maybe I have some time later to try this. I'm not sure if there is an option to have anchors that move and sit on the side that makes the shortest connection. That would also help you I guess

Comment: @Inaimathi: Any solution/fix for this.? I am facing the same issue. When i move the child and try moving the parent the child's endpoints go to the original position.

Comment: @SandeepNayak - My solution came down to "Don't use jsPlumb for that". Sorry I can't offer more help.